# temp table is deleted before data can be displayed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php page that lets me select dates and then run a query that does a few things and then makes a temp table with the data. 
NEXT, I want to display that data on the page. However, the connection is closed so the data is gone.

How can I extract that data before the tables are removed. 
I need the tables removed so that I can run the query again with slightly different variables, when I use regualr tables I have to reload the page than some of my query code removes the table. I tried adding a clean query at the end, but I think the posting, messes me up there.

....

```
<?php
```

//create the table

```
$query   = "Drop TABLE if exists temp_pers;";
$query  .= "CREATE temp table temp_pers (seqid integer, Name character(90));";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO temp_pers (seqid, Name)
SELECT per_id, CONCAT('<a href=PersonView.php?PersonID=',per_ID,'>',per_FirstName,' ', per_LastName,'</a>')
    FROM person_per
    WHERE per_id in 
        (SELECT DISTINCT person_id 
            FROM event_attend, events_event
            WHERE events_event.event_type = $group_id and
            date(checkin_date) >= '$dStartDate' and
            date(checkin_date) <= '$dEndDate' and
            event_attend.event_id = events_event.event_id)
ORDER by per_LastName, per_FirstName
;";

#Dates Query
$query  .= "Drop TABLE if exists temp_dates ;";
$query  .= "CREATE temp table temp_dates (meet_date date);";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO temp_dates (meet_date)
SELECT DISTINCT date(event_start)
    FROM event_attend, events_event
    WHERE events_event.event_type = $group_id and
    date(checkin_date) >= '$dStartDate' and
    date(checkin_date) <= '$dEndDate' and
    event_attend.event_id = events_event.event_id
        ORDER BY 1;";
#Final query
$query  .= "Drop TABLE if exists pers_dates;";
$query  .= "CREATE temp table pers_dates (pers_id integer, pers_name character(90), pers_date date, pers_date_attend_ind character(1) NOT NULL default' ');";
$query  .= "INSERT INTO pers_dates(pers_id, pers_name, pers_date)
SELECT temp_pers.seqid, temp_pers.name, temp_dates.meet_date
FROM temp_pers, temp_dates
Where 1=1;";
#update the "y"
$query  .= "UPDATE pers_dates SET pers_date_attend_ind = 'Yes' 
            WHERE EXISTS (SELECT person_id, checkin_date From event_attend, events_event 
            WHERE events_event.event_type= $group_id and pers_id = person_id 
            and pers_date = date(checkin_date) 
            and event_attend.event_id = events_event.event_id);";






mysqli_multi_query($dbc, $query);
```

//display the table

```
if(isset($_POST['AttendanceSubmit'])){ // button name

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT pers_id , pers_name, pers_date, pers_date_attend_ind FROM pers_dates") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) $rows[] = $row;
    foreach($rows as $key => $value)
    {
        $array[$value['pers_id']]['name'] = $value['pers_name'];
        $array[$value['pers_id']]['dates'][$value['pers_date']] = $value['pers_date_attend_ind'];
    }

    //$rowColor = "brown";
    function generate_table($array)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $html .= '<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="9">'; // start table inside the loop. It will looks better due to each member may have different number of date count.
            $html .= '<tr bgcolor="#F3E2A9">';
            $html .= '<td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>';
            foreach($value['dates'] as $k => $v)
            {
                //Date of meeting
                $html .= '<td>' .' '. $k .' '. '</td>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
            $html .= '<tr>';
            //Person name
            $html .= '<td align="center">' . $value['name'] . '</td>';
            foreach($value['dates'] as $v)
            {
                //attendance indicator
                $html .= '<td align="center">' . $v .' ' . '</td>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
            $html .= '</table>';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    echo generate_table($array);


$clean="Drop TABLE temp_pers, temp_dates, pers_dates;";
mysqli_query($dbc,$clean);      


?>
```

Comment: Why do you create such table? You can store the data with PHP?

Comment: Can you elaborate, I don't know another way to do it.

Comment: Can you limit the code you're posting to the relevant part ? I don't think someone wants to read 200 lines of your code.

Comment: I think I cut as much as I can...Anymore and I don't think it will make sense.

Comment: You answered your own question.  If you close the connection, you lost the temp table as the table will be available only to the connection that created it.

Comment: Can I keep it open? From what I read mysqli doesn't allow for the keep open option anymore.

Comment: temp tables are automatically dropped when the connection that created them is closed. if you're creating them in one script instance and then trying to use them in another script instance, then what you want is impossible - temp tables are also locked to the connection that created them. you cannot access another session's temp tables.

Comment: How about storing the query, or the information that tells you how to create the temp table in $_SESSION and only create the temp table when you are ready to use it.

Comment: Thanks @marcB that answers my question though it doesn't solve the problem... I do appreciate the help.